# Sylius - ERROR {"code":500,"message":"Could not resolve argument $em

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I need to retrieve my repository in my function in a Custom Controller I've created but it gives me the following error:

`{"code":500,"message":"Could not resolve argument $em of \"App\\Controller\\LicenceController::getlicencecodecrm()\", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the \"controller.service_arguments\"?"}`

sylius_ressource.yaml:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        ############## Licence ##############
        app.licence:
            driver: doctrine/orm # You can use also different driver here
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Licence\Licence
                repository: App\Repository\LicenceRepository
                form : App\Form\LicenceType
```

services.yaml :

```
    App\Controller\LicenceController:
        autowire: false
        public: true
```

LicenceController.php :

```
`    public function getLicenceCodeCrm(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        // $repo = $this->get('App\Repository\LicenceRepository');
        $repo = $em->getRepository(Licence::class);
        $criteria = $request->query->get('phrase');
        $q = $criteria['search']['value'];

        $items = $repo->findByNamePart($q);

        return new JsonResponse([
            '_embedded' => [
                'items' => $items,
            ]
        ]);
    }`
```

LicenceRepository :

```
    public function findByNamePart(string $codeCrm, ?int $limit = null): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->andWhere('o.codeCrm LIKE :code')
            ->setParameter('code', '%' . $codeCrm . '%')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: Your controller doesn't know what `EntityManagerInterface $em` is. Either re-enable auto wiring or define your controller arguments in services.yaml.

Comment: Thanks @craigh for your response  but I have already this in routes.yml :





`app_admin_ajax_order_by_name_phrase:
    path: /admin/order/search
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: App\Controller\LicenceController::getLicenceCodeCrm
        _format: json
        _sylius:
            serialization_groups: [Autocomplete]
            permission: true
            repository:
                method: findByNamePart
                arguments:
                    phrase: $phrase
                    limit: 25`

Comment: and clearly that is not working for you. Maybe try what I suggested.